# Multi-statement query for selecting two rows at a time

Tags: sql

Is there any way to perform a SQL query where I search by multiple dependent clauses? Like if I had a table of Humans, I would want to get back all humans of `(Type = Student and id = 1)` && `(Type = Teacher and id = 44)`. As you can imagine, I can expand each bracket to multiple statements per bracket and even add a third, fourth bracket to query by more types.

The table is as follows:

```
Humans
id
type
name
```

So far, I am forced to call the same query many times where I do a

```
select * 
from t_humans 
where type = a_type and id = an_id
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please add back the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff This would be for Psql and the where (x, y) in (...) clause is not quite supported. Any way to do this via sbuqueries/derived tables or any thing of that nature?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, a generic SQL method is to use more complex boolean conditions:

```
select h.*
from t_humans h
where (type = 'Student' and id = 1) or
      (type = 'Teacher' and id = 44);
```

Some databases allow you to simplify this by using tuples with `in`:

```
select h.*
from t_humans h
where (type, id) in (('Student', 1), ('Teacher', 44));
```

Comment: Ah, I am using PSQL and a specialized parser that auto-generates java queryable sql queries. This auto-generation does not support the IN predicate. Any way to do this with ANY? Or a more complex query joining itself or something like that? I am not very experienced with psql/sql